# HBase - Error: java.io.IOException: The connection has to be unmanaged - Client Squirrel SQL

Tags: hive, hbase

I am trying to query HBase data through an HIVE external table. The query comes through a client, at this time it is Squirrel SQL. If i query through simple HIVE command line interface i am able to query the Hive external table (stored in HBASE) 
  However when i query through Squirrel SQL i get the error

```
Error: java.io.IOException: The connection has to be unmanaged.
```

The following is my environment
HBase - 1.1.5
Hive  - 1.2.1
Hadoop - 2.6.0
Zookeeper - 3.4.6 Runs on 3 nodes

Please help.

Regards

Bala

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this out as well. This was due to jar mismatch. Once i got all the right jars lined up and started thriftserver with --jars, this error went away.

Thanks

Bala